# Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have created windows service in .Net 4.5.Service is written to open outlook client. The code written is correct, since I have run in local host. But when I run from IIS Server, the server throws following error on following line of code:

> Error retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 0x80040154 Class not registered

I tried the following solutions:

`IIS Server > Advanced Settings > Enable 32 Bit APP = true & Identity=Windows`

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The IIS runs in a low privilege mode, I believe it is `NETWORK SERVICE`.  This account is restricted heavily from using client-related COM objects, and Outlook client is registered under the respective user account.  Technically, you change the (COM configuration)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/hkey-local-machine-software-microsoft-ole], but you should not do it.

Office objects, including Outlook, **require** a logged user session.  With Outlook in particular, it requires a logged user who also has a registered Outlook profile, and an Exchange license (if applicable).

In your case, when you run it from the local host, you have such a session - yours.  When you run it on IIS, this session is not available.

What you want to do if **officially not supported** and is greatly [discouraged](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: Though you linked to the right Microsoft KB article, some of the sentences are not 100% correct. "This session is not available" should be replaced by "this is in session 0 and isolated", https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/